# Getting the value associated with an integer key from an object, if the key exists (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Currently, I have an object with integer keys for certain values. I do not know that each key actually exists on the object yet, however.

Usually, I would be able to perform

```
Object?.parentKey?.childKey
```

to find the value of `childKey`, if it exists. If childKey is an integer, however, then

```
Object?.parentKey?.0
```

does not work.

```
Object['parentKey.0']
```

doesn't work either. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: _"I have an object with integer keys"_ - No, you haven't. The keys in an object are always strings (or symbols).

Comment: @Andreas This object is pulled from a database where the keys were set with integers, I understand that to JavaScript it is still treated as a string, however that didn't change the fact that the above methods wouldn't work with the key I needed. Thanks for the correction but that didn't really help at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

`Object?.parentKey?.0` doesn't work since valid javascript [identifiers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Identifier) can't start with a number.

> In JavaScript, identifiers are case-sensitive and can contain Unicode
> letters, `$`, `_`, and digits (0-9), but may not start with a digit.

`Object['parentKey.0']` doesn't work unless there's a key that is literally `"parentKey.0"`, i.e. `{ "parentKey.0": "value" }`

## Solution

Access like a dynamic object key ([Computed Property Names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#computed_property_names))

```
object?.parentKey?.[0]
```

or

```
object?.parentKey?.['0']
```

```js
const object = {
  parentKey: {
    0: 'hello world!',
  },
};

console.log(object?.parentKey?.[0]);
```